# iOS - MVC 1 or MVC 2?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I need to know whether iOS is based on MVC1 or MVC2 architecture for a thesis.

I guess it uses MVC2 because everything goes through the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite that clear cut.  The design pattern that is implemented in UIKit is Model-View-Controller.  There's no "Model 1" or "Model 2" MVC design pattern.

"Model 1" and "Model 2" were terms invented by Sun that described two different ways of implementing the MVC pattern with JSPs.

In Model 1 the M is JavaBeans in the JSP, the V is the HMTL/scriptlets in the JSP and the C is the JSP Servlet that selected the JSP to execute based on the URI passed to the container.

In Model 2 a more rigid separation of concerns was recommended.  So for example, in the Spring MVC framework the M is whatever your business logic is, the V is whichever templating language you decide to use (Freemarker, JSP/JSTL, Velocity) and the C is the DispatcherServlet, which selects the Controller implementation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2